# MATLAB: export scalars within for loop to text file

Tags: matlab, for-loop, writefile

I have a large number of text files that I have to read, find the max value for a certain column, and the corresponding time.  The for loop for finding these values works fine, but my problem is writing a text file that shows the three variables I need (thisfilename, M, and wavetime) for each iteration of the for loop.

```
Output_FileName_MaxWaveHeights = ['C:\Users\jl44459\Desktop\QGIS_and_Basement\BASEMENT\Mesh_5_2045\Run_A\','MaxWaveHeights.txt'];
writefile = fopen(Output_FileName_MaxWaveHeights,'a');

dinfo = dir('*.dat');
for K = 1 : length(dinfo)
    thisfilename = dinfo(K).name;  %just the name of the file
    fileID = fopen(thisfilename);  %creates numerical ID for the file name
    thisdata = textscan(fileID,'%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64',500,'HeaderLines',1); %load just this file
    thisdataM = cell2mat(thisdata); %transforms file from cell array to matrix
    [M,I] = max(thisdataM(:,5)); %finds max WSE and row it's in
    wavetime = 2*(I-1); %converts column of max WSE to time
    fprintf(writefile,'%s %8.4f %4.0f \r\n',thisfilename,M,wavetime);
    fclose(fileID); %closes file to make space for next one
end
```

The text file ends up just giving me the values for one iteration instead of all of them.  I was able to use displaytable as a workaround, but then I have problems writing "thisfilename", which includes non-numerical characters.

Comment: How about saving the values in a cell and write the cell to the file outside the for-loop?

Comment: I don't see you closing the output file `fclose(writefile )` at the end after the loop. Did you forget to include it in the example ?

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not able to reproduce the issue with the code provided, a possible solution might be to write to the file outside of the loop and to close the file afterwards:

```
Output_FileName_MaxWaveHeights = ['C:\Users\jl44459\Desktop\QGIS_and_Basement\BASEMENT\Mesh_5_2045\Run_A\','MaxWaveHeights.txt'];
writefile = fopen(Output_FileName_MaxWaveHeights,'a');

s = [];
dinfo = dir('*.dat');
for K = 1 : length(dinfo)
    thisfilename = dinfo(K).name;  %just the name of the file
    fileID = fopen(thisfilename);  %creates numerical ID for the file name
    thisdata = textscan(fileID,'%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64%f64',500,'HeaderLines',1); %load just this file
    thisdataM = cell2mat(thisdata); %transforms file from cell array to matrix
    [M,I] = max(thisdataM(:,5)); %finds max WSE and row it's in
    wavetime = 2*(I-1); %converts column of max WSE to time
    s = [s, fprintf(writefile,'%s %8.4f %4.0f \r\n',thisfilename,M,wavetime)];
    fclose(fileID); %closes file to make space for next one
end

fprintf(writefile,s);
fclose(writefile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved--it was simply me forgetting to close the output file after the loop.  Thanks for the help!